# Check object variable exists when using object destructuring

Tags: javascript

I have a 'getData' function which gets passed a 'data' variable. Inside the function I'm trying to access an object 'data.someObject' which may or may not exist because it comes from an outside library.

What is the best approach to check if it does exist before trying to use it? Also see I'm using object destructuring here aswell.

```
const getData = (data) => {
    const { name, age } = data.someObject; // someObject may or may not exist
    console.log(name, age);
}
```

I thought doing this might work:

```
const { name, age } = data.someObject || {};
```

But I wasn't sure if that would throw an error.

Thanks

Comment: Well it will throw an error anyway if the `someObject` field doesn't exist, add a try/catch block if you want to catch the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `||` & if required provide default values while destructuring.

```js
function print(user) {
  const { fname = "Anonymous", lname = "Panda" } = user.fullname || {};

  console.log(`Hello ${fname} ${lname}`);
}

print({ fullname: { fname: "John", lname: "Doe" } });
print({});
print({ fullname: null });
```

Comment: Thanks, so what I suggested would work ok? The values wouldn't need to have fallbacks undefined is fine. Would the object be null or undefined if an external library didn't return it?

Comment: @JoeConsterdine Yeah using `||` works fine, and it depends on the library how they're structuring the response, but both `null` and `undefined` would work fine with `||`.

Comment: @JoeConsterdine Added an example for `null` in the above code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would put an `if` statement:

```
const getData = (data) => {
  if (data.someObject == null) {
    // Here you can return, throw an error or do anything else you might need
  }
  const { name, age } = data.someObject; // someObject may or may not exist
  console.log(name, age);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but why doesn't:

const { name, age } = data.someObject || {};

Do the same? As here I'm checking if the object is falsy (including null) and assigning it an empty object if it is.

Comment: Because it will assign `undefined` to both `name` and `age`. You can add a default value if you want by doing `const { name = 'foo', age = 42 }`. It depends what is your function supposed to do when `someObject` is not defined

Comment: Yeah that's fine, I was more just wanting to handle the error if the object didn't exist. Assigning undefined to name and age is ok. Thanks!